# how to verify a PSS signature with a non-matching MGF1 / Hash?

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

PSS RSA signatures have three options per https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-9.1.1 :

- Hash: "*hash function (hLen denotes the length in octets of the hash function output)*"
- MGF: "*mask generation function*"
- sLen: "*intended length in octets of the salt*"

The [PSSOptions struct](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rsa#PSSOptions), however, only has two options:

```
type PSSOptions struct {
    // SaltLength controls the length of the salt used in the PSS signature. It
    // can either be a positive number of bytes, or one of the special
    // PSSSaltLength constants.
    SaltLength int

    // Hash is the hash function used to generate the message digest. If not
    // zero, it overrides the hash function passed to SignPSS. It's required
    // when using PrivateKey.Sign.
    Hash crypto.Hash
}
```

So how do I verify a PSS signature where the Hash and the MGF are different?

In Java there's `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding` and depending on the crypto service provider you're using the MGF is either hard-coded as sha1 or it's the same as the regular Hash. Maybe PSS signatures in Go work similarly? Altho even if it is that still leaves the question of how to verify such signatures up in the air.

Comment: The specification of different digests for PSS is presumably not supported by crypto/rsa, see issue [#46233: crypto/rsa: allow hash.Hash for PSS and MGF1 to be specified independently](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46233).

Comment: Just a small note: there is only one option for the MGF: MGF1. However, the MGF1 function itself has a single configuration parameter: the hash used. So SHA-1 *isn't* the MGF, it *configures MGF1*.